# карта не выводися на экран

Tags: c++, sfml

пишу игру на С++ хочу создать карту через матрицу, создал матрицу, написал циклы i && j сделал все как по видео https://youtu.be/6OHMFwQK44k по идеи должно вывестись черные квадраты 32 на 32 и зеленые квадраты 32 на 32 вот сам код

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int ground = 150;




const int H = 12;
const int W = 40;


String TileMap[H] = {

    "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
    "B                                B     B",
    "B                                B     B",
    "B                                B     B",
    "B                                B     B",
    "B         0000                BBBB     B",
    "B                                B     B",
    "BBB                              B     B",
    "B              BB                BB    B",
    "B              BB                      B",
    "B    B         BB         BB           B",
    "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",

};















class Player
{

public:

    float dx, dy;
    FloatRect rect;
    bool onGround;
    Sprite sprite;
    float currentFrame;

    Player(Texture& image)
    {
        sprite.setTexture(image);
        rect = FloatRect(59, 0, 59, 9);

        dx = dy = 0.1;
        currentFrame = 0;
    }

    void update(float time)
    {

        rect.left += dx * time;

        if (!onGround) dy = dy + 0.0005 * time;
        rect.top += dy * time;
        onGround = false;

        if (rect.top > ground) { rect.top = ground; dy = 0; onGround = true; }

        currentFrame += 0.0015 * time;
        if (currentFrame > 4) currentFrame -= 4;

        //if (dx > 0) sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(59 * int(currentFrame), 0, 59, 99));
        //if (dx < 0) sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(59 * int(currentFrame)+ 59, 0, -59, 99));

        sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(59 * int(currentFrame), 0, 59, 99));



        sprite.setPosition(rect.left, rect.top);

        dx = 0;
    }
};







int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 700), "G.A.M.E"); // создаем окно, задаем разрешение экрана и даем название окна
    //CircleShape MyCircle(100.f);
    //MyCircle.setFillColor(Color::Green);

    Texture t;
    t.loadFromFile("а.png"); //загружаем текстуру
    
    

    float perehod = 0;

    Player p(t);
   

    Clock clock;

    RectangleShape rectangle;

    while (window.isOpen()) //главный цикл игры, пока окно открыто
    {
        float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds();
        clock.restart();

        time = time / 800;

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)// если закрыть окно окно закроется
                window.close();
        }
        
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
        {
            p.dx = -0.2;
        }
       
       // s.setColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 32)); сделать текстуру прозрачной
       // s.setScale(1.5);
        
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
        {
            p.dx = 0.2;
          

        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S))
        {
            p.dy = 0.4;
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
        {
            if (p.onGround) { p.dy = -0.4; p.onGround = false; }
        }
        p.update(time);

        window.clear(Color::White);

        for (int i = 0; i < H; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < W; j++)
            {
                if (TileMap[i][j] == 'B') rectangle.setFillColor(Color::Black);

                if (TileMap[i][j] == '0')  rectangle.setFillColor(Color::Green);

                if (TileMap[i][j] == ' ') continue;

                rectangle.setPosition(j * 32, i * 32);
                window.draw(rectangle);
            }
     

        
        
        window.draw(p.sprite);
        
        window.display();
    }


  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: у `RectangleShape rectangle` не задан размер

Comment: *"по идеи должно вывестись черные квадраты 32 на 32 и зеленые квадраты 32 на 32"* -- а выводит что? Приведите скрин с помощью кнопки править

Comment: Кастомные строки в C++ ни к чему хорошему не приведут(при твоём опыте). Как и попытка сделать карту через просто строку. И ты уж определись у тебя плавающий фреймрейт или фиксированный. А то получится так, что на мощном пк прыжок выше. И вообще стоит сделать класс вектора для положения по x, y и dx, dy, а ещё лучше взять из glm классы векторов. А вообще уроки какие-то слабые очень, и код в них плохой.